# Why are extra cells being added to my calendar between the days of the week?

Tags: javascript

So for my JavaScript course, our book walks us through the creation of a calendar.  I thought I copied everything exactly as it appeared in the book, but maybe not.  For some reason, blank cells are being inserted between the names of the days of the week.  This obviously should not happen.  What am i doing wrong?

This is my full script:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Web 240 Assignment 3</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            table {
                background: #ccc;
                border: 1px solid #999;
                padding: 3px;
            }
            #calendar_head {
                background: red;
                color: white;
                font-weight: bold;
                text-align: center;
            }
            .calendar_weekdays {
                background: white;
                border-bottom: 5px solid #ccc;
                font-weight: bold;
            }
            .calendar_dates {
                background: white;
                padding: 5px 25px 10px 5px;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function calendar(){

                document.write('<table id="calendar_table">');

                var calDate = new Date();
                writeCalTitle(calDate);
                writeDayNames();
                writeCalDays(calDate);

                document.write('</table>');
            }
            function writeCalTitle(calendarDay){

                var monthName = new Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");

                var thisMonth = calendarDay.getMonth();
                var thisYear = calendarDay.getFullYear();

                document.write("<tr>");
                document.write('<th id="calendar_head" colspan="7">');
                document.write(monthName[thisMonth] + " " + thisYear);
                document.write('</th>');
                document.write('</tr>');
            }

            function writeDayNames(){

                var dayName = new Array("Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat");
                document.write('<tr>');

                for(var i = 0; i < dayName.length; i++){

                    document.write('<th class="calendar_weekdays">' + dayName[i] + "<th>");

                }

                document.write("</tr>");

            }

            function daysInMonth(calendarDay){

                var thisYear = calendarDay.getFullYear();
                var thisMonth = calendarDay.getMonth();
                var dayCount = new Array(31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31,31, 30, 31, 30, 31);

                if(thisYear % 4 == 0){

                    if((thisYear % 100 != 0) || (thisYear % 400 == 0)){

                        dayCount[1] = 29;

                    }

                }

                return dayCount[thisMonth];

            }

            function writeCalDays(calendarDay){

                var dayCount = 1;
                var totalDays = daysInMonth(calendarDay);

                calendarDay.setDate(1);
                var weekDay = calendarDay.getDay();

                document.write('<tr>');
                for(var i = 0; i < weekDay; i++){

                    document.write('<td></td>');

                }

                while(dayCount <= totalDays){

                    if(weekDay == 0) document.write('<tr>');
                    document.write('<td class="calendar_dates">' + dayCount + "</td>");
                    if(weekDay == 6) document.write('</tr>');

                    dayCount++;
                    calendarDay.setDate(dayCount);
                    weekDay = calendarDay.getDay();

                }

            }
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">calendar();</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the output:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5OHa.jpg

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Your problem is `'<th class="calendar_weekdays">' + dayName[i] + "<th>"`. The `+ "<th>"`should be `+ "</th>"`, otherwise you will create an additional empty `<th></th>`.  I know that this is just testing code. But you still should not use `document.write`. A better idea would be to build a large string and then add it using e.g. `innerHTML` to your document, that way you could also output your final html code and validate it.

Comment: Thanks, I actually spotted that right before you posted... lol.  And I agree about using innerHTML with one large string.  I am a PHP programmer and I am getting my degree in Web Development and this book is from 2012 so the ideas might be slightly outdated.